Gitlab ci won't run my scripts as it requires a database connection
I’m attempting to run a unit test within gitlab, the test functions correctly on my local enviornment but I encounter the error below in Gitlab.
I'm guessing gitlab does not have access to the database, which is why the script is failing on saving the file to the database.
Here is the error message I recevied in Gitlab
Error message:
[ERROR] Failures: 
[ERROR]   AnnualReturnServiceTest.testSave:102 
Wanted but not invoked:
annualReturnRepository.save(
    <any com.riskanalysisexpertsystem.scanpro.model.company.AnnualReturn>
);
-> at com.test.unit.AnnualReturnServiceTest.testSave(AnnualReturnServiceTest.java:102)
Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.

Here is the script for AnnualReturnServiceTest.testSave
public class AnnualReturnServiceTest{
    
    private Logger logger;
    private PDFtoImageConverterUtility pdftoImageConverterUtility;
    private final String SOURCE_FILE_PATH = "../scanpro/src/test/resources/files/taxdocuments/company/annual_return_form.pdf";
    private final String SOURCE_DESTINATION_PATH = "../scanpro/src/test/resources/files/taxdocuments/company/annual_return.png";
    
    @Mock
    private AnnualReturnRepository annualReturnRepository;
    
    @Mock
    private OcrUtility ocrUtility;
    
    @InjectMocks
    private AnnualReturnService annualReturnService;
    
    @BeforeClass
    public void setUpBeforeClass() throws Exception{
        logger = LogManager.getLogger(AnnualReturnServiceTest.class);
        pdftoImageConverterUtility = new PDFtoImageConverterUtility();
        MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);
    }

    public void testSave() {
        logger.info("Mock file and file details");
        
        pdftoImageConverterUtility.convertFile(SOURCE_FILE_PATH, SOURCE_DESTINATION_PATH);
        File file = new File(SOURCE_DESTINATION_PATH);
        String fileDetails = "Annual Return Form\n"
                + "Company Name: Apple Inc.\n"
                + "\n"
                + "TIN: 3243243\n"
                + "\n"
                + "Company Address: 32432 MaryDale Drive., Ghana 234324\n"
                + "Company Registration Number: 432432\n"
                + "Fiscal Year Start Date: 2022-01\n"
                + "\n"
                + "Fiscal Year End Date: 2022-12\n"
                + "\n"
                + "Total Revenue: 342432\n"
                + "\n"
                + "Total Expenses: 3434\n"
                + "\n"
                + "Taxable Income: 34333\n"
                + "\n"
                + "Tax Paid: 3243";
        
        logger.info("Mock the behaviour of OCR utility");
        when(ocrUtility.performOCR(file)).thenReturn(fileDetails);
        
        logger.info("Call the save method");
        annualReturnService.save(file);
        
        logger.info("Verify that parseAnnualReturnDetails is not null");
        try {
            assertNotNull(annualReturnService.parseAnnualReturnDetails(fileDetails));
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        logger.info("Verify the annualReturnRepository's save method is called");
        verify(annualReturnRepository, times(1)).save(any(AnnualReturn.class));
    }
}

AnnualReturnService
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class AnnualReturnService {
    
    private final AnnualReturnRepository annualReturnRepository;

    public void save(File file) {
        
        OcrUtility ocrUtility = new OcrUtility();
        String fileDetails = ocrUtility.performOCR(file);
        
        if (fileDetails != null) {
            
            AnnualReturn annualReturn = new AnnualReturn();
            try {
                annualReturn = parseAnnualReturnDetails(fileDetails);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            
            if (annualReturn != null) {
                annualReturnRepository.save(annualReturn);
            }
        }
    }

.gitlab-ci
test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - mvn test -Dtest=com.test.unit.AnnualReturnServiceTest
  allow_failure: true
  dependencies:
    - build
  artifacts:
    paths: 
      - target/surefire-reports
    expire_in: "30 days"


the error from gitlab looks like a Mockito verification error which has nothing to do with database access.
There are two obvious causes for this.

There is logic in the service under test which when given the test mock conditions avoids the annualReturnRepository.save() call.
Your mocks are not injected into the service correctly.

Maybe you can provide the test definition and some code from the service under test.
PS if you only want to verify a single method call it's ok to skip the times(1)
verify(annualReturnRepository).save(any(AnnualReturn.class));

After author added test definitions
Looking at the test this seems very out of place
assertNotNull(annualReturnService.parseAnnualReturnDetails(fileDetails));

You should only call a single method from the service under test. Also the
any(AnnualReturn.class) // also checks for null

I think that whatever happens in parseAnnualReturnDetails returns some non-null result when you call it from the test but when it is called from the actual service under test it returns a null AnnualReturn avoiding the repo call and triggering the Mockito verify error.

I've updated the verify section of the test but I'm still experiencing the error

Hey AbstractKamen, thank you for your feedback. I'm new to mockito and testing. How would you go about fixing this error?

Hello you should remove the ‘parseAnnualReturnDetails()’ call from the test. Then check if something else needs to be mocked so that ‘parseAnnualReturnDetails’ returns a result when called from the service under test.

Also I’m not sure how you run your tests when you say it works locally. Have you tried using mvn test -Dtest=com.test.unit.AnnualReturnServiceTest to better replicate the GitLab conditions?

When I run the test as testng test within eclipse, I get the following output: 05:21:34.333 [main] INFO com.test.unit.AnnualReturnServiceTest -- Mock the behaviour of OCR utility
05:21:34.386 [main] INFO com.test.unit.AnnualReturnServiceTest -- Call the save method
05:21:37.386 [main] INFO com.test.unit.AnnualReturnServiceTest -- Verify that parseAnnualReturnDetails is not null
05:21:37.393 [main] INFO com.test.unit.AnnualReturnServiceTest -- Verify the annualReturnRepository's save method is called

Hey AbstractKamen, thank you for your suggestions. You are right its not a database issue but a script error. I've updated the script and it works properly.
